# Is it possible for the compiler to have a maximum on output?

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

[original text][1]

[results when i print out within Server Class][2]

In my Server Class I want to read each line of the text file, including empty lines but it starts in the middle of the file.  I believe it has to do with the ecplise max output.  I know because I get the correct output of bytes from each line.

Comment: Your code only reads a single line.  You should use a loop and iterate over the file.

Comment: Nonsense. It reads everything in the file, and stops at EOF. It works for everybody else. NB The only thing you're sending here is the line length, not the line itself. Are you ever closing or flushing `pr`?

Comment: Then you should look it up. `pr.flush()`, before you do the next read from the socket.

Comment: Now you're claiming it begins from the middle of the file, which not only is impossible but contradicts your original claim.

Comment: @EJP i will upload the results, why would i make this up ?

Comment: When are you going to make up your mind what the symptoms are? When are you going to implement the flush I suggested?

Comment: i did and there was no difference

Comment: Not shown above, so impossible to comment, except that in the code above it should be after the read loop. In fact the code above doesn't send anything anywhere except to `System.out`, so it's all pretty pointless. Maybe the client code has bugs too: who could possibly know from this evidence?

Comment: @EJP i just uploaded two images in the above code   one is the original text and the second is my results

Comment: So this isn't the real code. Recompile, rebulld, retest. Or there is more text further up in the console window.

Comment: @EJP it was a simple eclipse max output setting, next time don't assume it is just code..because the code was not the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some kind of loop to iterate through the BufferedReader. If readLine() returns null, you're at the end of the stream and you can break out of the loop.

See API for [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()).

Comment: @Nameishi As you've accepted this answer, you should delete all your comments claiming it doesn't work, and/or explain what was preventing it working *for you.* Was it just a recompile? Or not posting the real code?

Comment: I changed the settings on ecplise, that was the issue.  Now I see the entire output. my code I provided works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Use a loop and iterate over the entire file:

```
while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null)) {
    pr.println(line);
}
```

Comment: @Nameish That can only mean that there was only one line in file, or you're not running the code you think you're running.

Comment: @Nameishi There's only one line there. QED. An HTML renderer would *render* it as several lines, but that's not what you asked, or what `BufferedReader` is for. Or a server.

Comment: It stops at EOF and not before.